# moment.js error "indexOf not supported"

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have downloaded the latest version of `moment.js` and tried this example from their website in my code:

```
alert(moment().subtract(10, 'days').calendar());
```

I get a message that the property or method IndexOf is not supported by this object.

I'm using Internet Explorer 11.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use IE?

Comment: It does work for me in IE

Comment: @LucaKiebel — "Not breaking on IE" is a fairly standard requirement for web development.

Comment: Are you sure the error is reported for this particular code? The code works fine in IE11.

Comment: indexOf() is not supported by IE earlier than IE 9, are you sure your IE is 11?

Comment: I don't think that this is a moment issue. The stated compatibility is IE8+.

Comment: Also make sure you don't have crippling backwards compatibility mode (e.g.  "document-mode" set to 8 or lower in Emulation settings). Works fine with non-crippled IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. This was helpfull. Turned out that this line was in the way:

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"
```

I deleted this line and it worked.